# logger field of AbstractRememberMeServices class returns null when extending PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices in spring security

Tags: spring-security, remember-me

I need to extend PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices class to override some methods of it.
but when I add any method in my new class (ExtendedPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices), the logger in autoLogin method of AbstractRememberMeServices causes null pointer exception in process of authenticating user with rememberMe token.
(PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices class extends AbstractRememberMeServices in spring security)

why this is happening? Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please do not "explain" your code, and actually put some effort into your question to help others reproduce your problem. That means include code samples, full debug logs and all steps to reproduce. Voted to close